Switching between turn-based and real-time with stateless state machine
I am working on a real-time rpg with a turn-based combat.
Currently I have standard state machines for a game state (real-time/combat) and for characters.
However I can't seem to find a decent way to switch between the two game states.
The main problems I identified so far are:

amount of characters in present in the scene (sometimes hundreds, not all in combat but can be brought into it) which may result with significant stutter when game switches
switching between game states should have minimum (preferably none) effect on characters that never entered the combat

I am fiddling with an idea of a stateless state machine for the characters. Generally it sums up to one state machine for all characters. Each character contains all the necessary data for all states and an id to an array of possible states. Then use current game state as characters’ state machine with each containing identical array of states. This would allow to switch seamlessly between turn-based and real-time.
On paper it looks like it could work. But I have a nagging feeling that I am missing something.
Did anyone tried this before or knows a better way?

What exactly is a "stateless state machine"? :P

@Charanor I admit it's not the best description :) Stateless as in web applications where all the necessary data for the request is supplied by the client. In this case each state would hold no data on its own and will only work with one provided by the character.

What exactly do you mean with "minimum effect on characters that never entered combat"? Do they still act in real-time? Do they still follow their usual behavior, but now in a turn-based manner? Or are they frozen until dragged into the fight? (The latter would probably be the easiest to implement with the fewest corner-cases to consider)

@Philipp 'they follow their usual behavior but in turn-based manner'. I want to avoid a situation where the path a character follows gets recalculated, or timed actions like working with an anvil, or a kitchen get restarted by simply reinitializing the same action but in the other mode.

@Jamek This is probably the most difficult to implement, because now everything the NPCs are able to do must be possible in both real-time and in turn-based mode-

@Philipp that's what I was afraid of, but I started to implement this and so far it doesn't seems too difficult. Main problem I think will be fact that initialization of any state will have to work for both modes. It will take a while, but once I'm done I'll let you guys know how it went.

Do you really need NPC:s non-combat actions to also be turn-based? Even Divinity: Original Sin 2 and Baldur's Gate 3's NPC:s do their "idle" actions in real-time even when the player activates turn-based mode, they will keep hammering the anvil or unloading their cart etc. Depending on the game they might even move around normally until they get close to the player.

@Charanor I'm not really sure. On one hand You might be right, on the other it might turn out to be easier to implement that it seems at the first glance and it may give a relatively same flow of time to everyone. I just felt it was worth a try.

I have implemented a limited version of this concept and there are few things I learned about it.
Cons:

it breaks encapsulation
sharing variables with other states (as a part of a character) pose a risk of overwriting them by different states if not careful
all real-time counterparts to strictly combat related states (such as attacks, etc.) serves only to cleanup and redirect to a proper state. Considering each will exists in memory only once is not a huge problem
counterparts for each state has to be initialized in a way that will allow the other to complete successfully after the switch

Pros:

it works. It allows to switch seamlessly unlimited amount of characters from one mode to the other without dedicating a tick to any of them

I don’t know if I would advise anyone to use this concept, however I will try to complete my game with it. It has some problems but seems to solve all of mine.
I’ll leave my thoughts on it here, maybe someone will find it useful.

The requirement that all the NPCs must be able to do everything they are able to do in both real-time and turn-based mode and (as far as reasonably possible) in the same way and leading to the same results, makes this a lot more complicated.
My approach would be to design the internal logic of the NPCs as agnostic as possible to whether it's executed in turn-based or in real-time mode. Then I would implement the game to be either primarily turn-based or primarily real-time, and fake the other mode. That means:

The game runs turn-based and fakes real-time by having all actors execute their turns simultaneously and without pause between turns. (One interesting challenge here is that NPCs must be able to deal with real-time events interrupting the execution of their turn and then decide a new turn with a reduced time budget)
or

The game runs real-time and fakes turn-based by pausing all actors and then giving each one a few seconds of real-time action to perform, one after the other.


This approach (in either variant) would mean that there is no reason for NPCs to even be aware of whether they are currently in turn-based or in real-time mode. So there is no complex state-switching logic to implement for them. The state switch between real-time and turn-based happens in the overarching manager system that executes the NPC logic.

I'm reminded of a comment that "real-time action games are just turn-based games that execute 60 turns per second".

You could use the command pattern so that an external mediator (like a Game object) calls a method like get_realtime_action or get_turnbased_action from you entities. That way, each entity has no idea what it's state is, it just knows how to respond to what is requested of it.
This is a very general suggestion, given I don't know much about how your game is set up, so if you want more info about the Command Pattern, you can check it out here: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html
